# QTcpSocket::connectToHost() crashing on windows XP

Tags: c++, qt, windows-xp, qtcpsocket, qtnetwork

I made a program that connects a QTcpSocket to a QTcpServer and it works fine on windows 7 but with windows xp it never connects and the program just closes

```
bool socket::connectToServer(QString ip){
    s->connectToHost(ip,1234);
    if(s->waitForConnected(3000)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

on windows xp, it never gets past the first line. the socket state changes from 0 to 1 to 2 (the socket has started establishing a connection) then closes. tried allowing port 1234 through firewall or disabling the firewall completely but it still crashes.

dose anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure `s` is valid? Try with a debugger.

Comment: yes, s is initiated in the socket constructor (and there are other functions that use     s->isConnected() that dont crash)